# ¿Como puedo leer por posiciones un archivo de texto en python y mostrarlo como una tabla?

Tags: python

Recién inicio y me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para leer un archivo de texto sin delimitadores, y mostrarlo en pantalla como una tabla en python y así luego saber y exportar en otro archivo los Códigos que tengo como duplicados.

Ejemplo:

**Archivo de entrada:**

112345678Luis PerezCalle los Alamos123456789

212345675Pepe PerezCalle los Alamos123456789

312345678Luis PerezCalle los Alamos123456789

**como debería mostrarse:**

ID Código   Nombre     Dirección        Teléfono

1 12345678 Luis Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789

2 12345675 Pepe Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789

3 12345678 Luis Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789

**Archivo nuevo con duplicados:**

ID Código   Nombre     Dirección        Teléfono

1 12345678 Luis Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789

**Archivo sin duplicados:**

ID Código   Nombre     Dirección        Teléfono

1 12345678 Luis Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789

2 12345675 Pepe Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789

Me dijeron que puedo utilizar pandas, pero aún no encuentro como, me ayudan por favor?.

**Lo que pude es cargar el archivo:**

```
archivo_nombre= 'ruta'

archivo = open(archivo_nombre,mode='r')
lineas_texto=archivo.read()
#id= lineas_texto[4:25] # identifico el campo
archivo.close()
print(lineas_texto)
```

Comment: Podrias hacerlo de alguna forma si es que la longitud de los valores fuese fija

Comment: Sinceramente te sugiero que utilices ```,``` como separador

Comment: En este caso las longitudes de los campos van a ser fijas por cada campo, por ejemplo para este caso sería así: id 1
Código 8
Nombres 12
Dirección 15
Telefono 9

Comment: Con el ID tendrías un problema ya que solo podrás guardar del 1 al 9 si quieres que sea su longitud de 1, pero igual, en un rato te doy un ejemplo

Comment: Te lo agradeceré muchísimo!. Lo de las longitudes era solo un ejemplo para que se entienda que serán tamaños fijos.

Comment: Lo siento estoy ocupado por lo que no he tenido tiempo de hacer el ejemplo pero te puedo guiar. Puedes utilizar subcadenas y expresiones regulares, si aún no lo resuelves y tengo tiempo te ayudo

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal seria separar los datos por comas, pero alternativamente a mi me funciono algo como esto, Usando [expresiones regulares](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
from re import findall

archivo = open('somedata.txt',mode='r')
for line in archivo:
    initial_number,final_number = findall("\d+",line)
    id, codigo = initial_number[0],initial_number[1:]
    name = "".join(findall("\D+(?=Calle)",line))
    address ="".join(findall("Calle \D+",line))

    print(id,codigo,name,address,final_number)
```

Lo cual da como salida:

```
1 12345678 Luis Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789
2 12345675 Pepe Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789
3 12345678 Luis Perez Calle los Alamos 123456789
```